# Qt: What is the opposite of QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I want to enable and disable editing of a QTableView widget on certain signals. I can disable it by:

```
table->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```

But how to turn it back on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If editTriggers is printed:

```
qDebug()<< table->editTriggers();
```

is obtained:

```
QFlags<QAbstractItemView::EditTriggers>(DoubleClicked|EditKeyPressed|AnyKeyPressed)
```

so it can be assumed that the default state is:

```
QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked | QAbstractItemView::EditKeyPressed | QAbstractItemView::AnyKeyPressed
```

---

Or a simpler solution is to save the state at the beginning as a member of the class:

***.h**

```
// ...
private:
    QAbstractItemView::EditTriggers default_trigger;
```

***.cpp**

```
// constructor
default_trigger = table->editTriggers();
```

and then in your function you use:

```
if(table->editTriggers() == QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers)
    table->setEditTriggers(default_trigger);
else
    table->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```